# Express: How to factor routes callback

Tags: javascript, express

So I have multiple routes like this:

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
    model.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      res.send(docs);
    });
  });

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    model.findById(req.params.id, function(err, doc) {
      res.send(doc);
    });
  });
```

multiplied by a lot.

I'd like to know if they would be a way to factor out that callback function like that:

```
app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
    model.find({}, sendInResponse);
  });

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    model.findById(req.params.id, sendInResponse);
  });
```

My problem is the `res` scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor it like this:

```
var find = function (queryFn) {                                          

  return function (req, res, next) {                                     

    var query  = queryFn.apply({ req: req, res: res });                  

    model.find(query, function (err, docs) {                             
      res.send(docs);                                                    
    });                                                                  

  }                                                                      

};
```

Now you have generic query middleware which you can use like this:

```
app.get('/user/:id', find(function () { return { id: this.req.params.id } });
```

This is just the tip of what's possible and you can even refactor it more. This is a route from an app I created which uses only generic middleware:

```
app.get('/users/:username',
        data.one('user', data_users.byUsername, 'params.username'),
        data.many(data_grows.byUserId, 'locals.user.id'),
        general.render('grows/index'));
```